# Is is possible to log everything that is printed to the terminal into a text file in C?

Tags: c, terminal, printf

I have a ton of printf statements and I would like to write all of them to a text file.  I realize I could just add fprintf statements after each one but is there a better way, such as a function, or should I just write my own function?  I feel like this is probably a standard procedure, I just don't know what it's called, so it's hard to find an answer by googling.

**EDIT:** Just for clarity, I'd like the output to keep going the terminal like normal, but also be printed to a file simultaneously.  Several people are suggesting bash commands.  When should those be executed?  After the program is run?

Comment: What @Mysticial said - and if by chance you are using X-windows - xterm has a feature (not enabled by default to do this since the Matrix movie) to do this

Comment: I'm on linux currently but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do: `./executable > outputfile 2>&1` or `./executable &> outputfile`

This will enable you to redirect both the standard output and the standard output to the `outputfile`.

Comment: I believe that is actually standard output and standard error though, at least that is what I thought it was. 1 is STDOUT 2 is STDERR.

Comment: Specifically http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930 so 2> redirects STDERR, and > redirects STDOUT, so using the 2>&1 redirects STDERR into the STDOUT stream. I believe

Comment: Does this work in normal shells too? (I've only used it in MSDOS).

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Based on everyones suggestions, I found [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) which is very helpful.  So correct me if I'm wrong but maybe I need to do:  ./executable &>outputfile  ?

Comment: @onaclov2000: You are right it was a mistake, it is stdout and not stdin. The answer is also updated with the `&>` redirection.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a UNIX type box, you can pipe the output through `tee`, which will deliver it to standard output *and* a file:

```
myProg | tee /tmp/myProg.out
```

There are also ways to do the same thing with standard error as well:

```
( myProg 2>&1) | tee /tmp/myProg.out_and_err
```

This of course depends on whatever shell you're using but that should work on the most common ones.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry for my ignorance but is this a bash command?  If so, when is it invoked?

Comment: @whats, yes it is. By that I mean tee is a Unix executable but the way you invoke it is with the bash pipes and redirection stuff. It will run fine on Linux. Where I have myProg, you should use the name of your own program/scrpit, of course.

Answer (score 3):

When the program is run, use the `>` bash operator to redirect the programs output to a text file:

IE

`myprogram > myfile.txt`

That will save everything normally outputted to the screen with `printf` to a file named myfile.txt.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Sorry if this is obvious but Where should this be placed in the code?  I also found [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) page.  Is this the same thing as what you're talking about?

Comment: It is a bash operator. That page is exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

How about to redirect the stdout to a file, like

```
int main ()
{
  freopen ("myfile.txt","w",stdout);
  printf ("This sentence is redirected to a file.");
  fclose (stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

code sample comes from c++ Reference for [freopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/freopen/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. What you suggested works great, but I'd actually like the output to print to the terminal and the file simultaneously.  It doesn't seem that freopen can do this but I may be mistaken?